# How to Make Multi-Client UDP Server

Tags: c++, mfc, udp

I want to implement a UDP server which only uses one port (port:6516) but can handle multiple packets from multiple clients. I have been told to create a listening socket but I couldn't get the idea. As fas as I know, only TCP can perform listening event.

Could someone tell me the correct and efficient method to serve this kind of purpose? I've been searching through all over the internet but eventually I still not getting my mind clear. Working steps are really much appreciated (for both server and client).

Thank you.

Comment: UDP sockets listen automatically.  There's no need to call the `listen` function, which like you said is designed for TCP (actually any connection-oriented protocol).

Answer (score 5):

Create a socket (`socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)`), `bind()` it to the port, start calling `recvfrom()` which tells you who sent a packet, and `sendto()` which sends a packet to a specific target IP/Port - You need to manage the list of clients yourself, the UDP socket is normally not associated with a specific remote IP/port but will accept data from and send data to anything you specify in the mentioned calls.

Comment: `bind()` is the important call here, that's what makes your socket listen on a particular port.